# Search by primary key and then sort

Tags: mysql, performance, sql-order-by, primary-key

I'm using MySQL and I have a database that I'm trying to use as the canonical version of data that I will be storing in different indexes. That means that I have to be able to retrieve a set of data quickly from it by primary key, but I also need to sort it on the way out. I can't figure out how to let MySQL efficiently do that.

My table looks like the following:

```
CREATE TABLE demo.widgets (
    id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -- lots more information I need
    awesomeness INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (id),
    INDEX IDX_AWESOMENESS (awesomeness),
    INDEX IDX_ID_AWESOMENESS (id, awesomeness)
);
```

And I want to do something along the lines of:

```
SELECT *
FROM demo.widgets
WHERE id IN (
    1,
    2,
    3,
    5,
    8,
    13 -- you get the idea
)
ORDER BY awesomeness
LIMIT 50;
```

But unfortunately I can't seem to get good performance out of this. It always has to resort to a filesort. Is there a way to get better performance from this setup, or do I need to consider a different database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to get an optimized query to fetch and retrieve like that, you need to have a key that orders by sort and then primary like so:

```
create table if not exists test.fetch_sort (
    id int primary key,
    val int,
    key val_id (val, id)
);

insert into test.fetch_sort
values (1, 10), (2, 5), (3, 30);

explain
select *
from test.fetch_sort
where id in (1, 2, 3)
order by val;
```

This will give a query that only uses the index for searching/sorting.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the documentation [ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/order-by-optimization.html). In particular, if the index used to select rows in the `WHERE` clause is different from the one used in `ORDER BY`, it won't be able to use an index for `ORDER BY`.

Comment: I understand why it doesn't work. I want to know if there is an index that can satisfy both the `WHERE` and `ORDER BY` in this query.